# problem to rspec update action using rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm facing a problem with rspec and controllers

i'm spec'ing an update action, so to do it i call the following code:

```
put :update, :id => "1", :ntp => {:name=>'myservah'}
```

My controller has the following code:

```
def update
 if @ntp.update_attributes(params[:ntp])
  flash.now[:notice] = "Successfully updated ntp."
 else
  flash.now[:error] = ((errors_to_a(@ntp)*'.<br />')+'.')
 end
 render :partial => 'update'
end
```

And i'm getting the following error:

Failure/Error: put :update, :id => "1", :ntp => {:name=>'myservah'}
     Missing partial ntps/update with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "#"

My question is: should i explicit say which handler i have? Today my partial is named '_update.js.erb'.

BTW, my code works, i render the "js" version of update, since i just run some scripts

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rails detects the format of the response from certain request parameters, including the http accept request header (intelligent guessing), the `:format` parameter or the page extension.

Unless specified, Rails default the request format to `:html`.

As you can see, your request defaults to `:html` which means Rails is trying to render the `_update.html.erb` template. There are a few changes you can apply to fix the issue:

1. Always specify the request format in the test, if different than html.

   ```
   # emulate a js request
   put :update, :id => "1", :ntp => {:name=>'myservah'}, :format => :js
   ```

   If the action is intended to respond to an AJAX request, run the test using the `xhr` method

   ```
   # emulate an XHR request
   xhr :put, :update, :id => "1", :ntp => {:name=>'myservah'}, :format => :js
   ```
2. Return 406 with any non-js response. Change `render :partial => 'update'` to

   ```
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js  { render :partial => 'update' }
     format.any { head 406 }
   end
   ```

Comment: i had to change just the controller and add the format.. thanks for the "406" tip.. btw the hxr syntax, at least in rspec 2.0.0 is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, it's `xhr`. I fixed the answer.